# Error while running automated scripts in robot framework

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, qa-developer, robot

**'pybot' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

I am installing Python, Pip, Robot Framework and its all needed libraries and its working fine.

1) Python, Pip & Robot Framework all are installed and working well.

[image: Python, Pip & Robot Framework all are installed and working well.]

After installing and insuring the versions. I liked python to the path of environmental variables.

2) Path of Python & its Script already added in an environmental variable.

[image: Path of Python & its Script already added in an environmental variable.]

But **pybot is not recognized** showing when running the automated script in a robot technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pybot start script has been deprecated in RF 3.1 - and thus, this is what you get. Github Issue regarding this topic: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2818